# Is the GIS Repository In Ubuntu in a different stream than the main repository?

Tags: qgis, postgis, ubuntu

I was checking out this:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuGIS
and it outlines how to install PPA for GIS.

I performed a basic apt-cache search on a few things and QGis and mapserver are available.

Such as:

```
$ apt-cache search mapserver
cgi-mapserver - CGI executable for MapServer
libmapscript-perl - Perl MapServer module
libmapscript-ruby - Ruby MapServer library
libmapscript-ruby1.8 - Ruby MapServer library
libmapscript-ruby1.9.1 - Ruby MapServer library
mapserver-bin - MapServer utilities
mapserver-doc - documentation for MapServer
php5-mapscript - php5-cgi module for MapServer
python-mapscript - Python library for MapServer
qgis-mapserver - Quantum GIS mapserver
```

Running linux mint Nadia which works out to be quantal for Ubuntu version (10.10)

Is there any difference for adding this package?  I notice that there is a testing version as well.  Is the package difference similar to stable, testing, and unstable in debian or are the packages the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For QGIS, I highly recommend the repositories listed on the [Download page](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/Download#26-Ubuntu) of the wiki. UbuntuGIS is usually not up to date imho.